# JavaScript destructuring with an array element

Tags: javascript, destructuring, spread-syntax

I have met the following questions in JavaScript:

```js
const [x1, ...[result]] = [3, 4, 5]
console.log([result])
```

I know x1 is 3, but why is the logging result [4] instead of [4,5]?

Comment: `result` is `4`, not `[ 4 ]`. `[ result ]` can never be `[ 4, 5 ]`. It seems to behave similarly to `const [first] = array;`; in this case, it seems to be spreading the rest of `[ 3, 4, 5 ]`, i.e. `[ 4, 5 ]` into `...[result]`, then destructuring `[ 4, 5 ]` into `[ result ]`; therefore `result` is `4`.

Answer (score 5):

So basically what is happening if we follow this syntax

```
const [a,...b] = [3,4,5]
```

Javascript creates an array called `b` and has the value `[4,5]`

But in your case what is happening is,

```
const [a,...[b]] = [3,4,5]
```

This is essentially assigning to only the first variable of the empty array with first value as `b`, which always equals `4` and not `[4,5]` as you expect.

So it's equivalent to the case below

```
const [a,...[b,c]] = [3,4,5]
```

the only difference is that you are not providing a variable `c` in your case.
So `b` would correspond to `4` and `c` would correspond to `5`